# RegEx Match multiple times in string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to extract values from a string which are between << and >>.  But they could happen multiple times.

Can anyone help with the regular expression to match these;

```
this is a test for <<bob>> who like <<books>>
test 2 <<frank>> likes nothing
test 3 <<what>> <<on>> <<earth>> <<this>> <<is>> <<too>> <<much>>.
```

I then want to foreach the GroupCollection to get all the values.

Any help greatly received.
Thanks.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Use a positive look ahead and look behind assertion to match the angle brackets, use `.*?` to match the shortest possible sequence of characters between those brackets. Find all values by iterating the `MatchCollection` returned by the `Matches()` method.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<=<<).*?(?=>>)");

foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(
    "this is a test for <<bob>> who like <<books>>"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

[LiveDemo in DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3QRzfh)

Comment: no pun intended but this is exactly what I'm after.  Thank you for you really quick responses.

Answer (score 4):

While [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892517/3832970) is a good example of using lookarounds for left and right hand context checking, I'd like to also add a LINQ (lambda) way to access matches/groups and show the use of simple numeric [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) that come handy when you want to extract only a part of the pattern:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

// ...

var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"<<(.*?)>>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Same approach with Peter's compiled `regex` where the whole match value is accessed via `Match.Value`:

```
var results = regex.Matches(s).Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value);
```

**Note**:

- `<<(.*?)>>` is a regex matching `<<`, then *capturing* any 0 or more chars *as few as possible* (due to the non-greedy `*?` quantifier) into Group 1 and then matching `>>`
- `RegexOptions.Singleline` makes `.` match newline (LF) chars, too (it does not match them by default)
- `Cast<Match>()` casts the match collection to a `IEnumerable<Match>` that you may further access using a lambda
- `Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)` only returns the Group 1 value from the current `x` match object
- Note you may further create a list of array of obtained values by adding `.ToList()` or `.ToArray()` after `Select`.

In the [demo C# code](https://ideone.com/VioI6Y), `string.Join(", ", results)` generates a comma-separated string of the Group 1 values:

```
var strs = new List<string> { "this is a test for <<bob>> who like <<books>>",
                              "test 2 <<frank>> likes nothing",
                              "test 3 <<what>> <<on>> <<earth>> <<this>> <<is>> <<too>> <<much>>." };
foreach (var s in strs) 
{
    var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"<<(.*?)>>", RegexOptions.Singleline)
            .Cast<Match>()
            .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
}
```

Output:

```
bob, books
frank
what, on, earth, this, is, too, much
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try one of these:

```
(?<=<<)[^>]+(?=>>)
(?<=<<)\w+(?=>>)
```

However you will have to iterate the returned MatchCollection.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
(<<(?<element>[^>]*)>>)*
```

This program might be useful:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/regulator/