# Substrings in String

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, substring

in my app I need to search for sub strings in a very long string. This string is read from a file with multiple lines.

I want to read the substring between "(" and ")" which are often available in the string and save them to an array.
Example of string:

```
bla bla bla ( text) bla bla bla bla (text) bla bla
bla ( text) bla bla bla bla (text) bla bla ( text )
```

The "text" parts are the ones I need.

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: You can probably use `Regex.Match` with an expression like `"(.+)" to match everything between brackets (but it will include the brackets...). You will get a lot of inspiration from reading [this earlier article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452/regex-match-multiple-times-in-string)

Comment: @floris there is no "Regex.Match" in obj-c. But the asker may want to check out the `NSRegularExpression` class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSScanner [Scanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and Scan up to the "(" first , then scan it, then scan up to the ")". Then get the last scan result.