# How to match multiple items with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have following  pattern `{(.*?)}` and it matchs 1 item only.

How I can match multiple items in C# from this text

> akjsd{OrderNumber} aksjd {PatientName}  aksjak sdj askdj
>   {PatientSurname} askdjh askdj {PatientNumber} aksjd aksjd aksjd kajsd
>   kasjd

to get list like

> {OrderNumber}
>
> {PatientName}
>
> {PatientSurname}
>
> {PatientNumber}

Thank you!

Comment: it works see http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/17

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh! it is not working here http://www.regexr.com/  Thank you!!!

Comment: Here is a previous answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452/regex-match-multiple-times-in-string?rq=1

Comment: @ClarkKent see http://www.regexr.com/395an

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh! I got it. I didnt use `/g` Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
string input = "akjsd{OrderNumber} aksjd {PatientName} aksjak sdj askdj {PatientSurname} askdjh askdj {PatientNumber} aksjd aksjd aksjd kajsd kasjd";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, "{(.*?)}");

foreach(Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this regex `{[^}]*}` (more efficient because `.*?` backtracks at each step) and do it like this:

```
var resultList = new StringCollection();
var myRegex = new Regex("{[^}]*}", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchResult = myRegex.Match(yourString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
    }
```