# Regex match multiple substrings inside a string

Tags: c#, regex, string

So I have this one string, which contains multiple occurrences of a substring. All of these strings have the following format: `<c@=someText>Content<c>`

Example:

```
This combination of plain text and <c=@flavor> colored text<c> is valid. <c=@warning>Multiple tags are also valid.<c>
```

I want to extract each of the substrings via regex. However if I use the following regex `<c=@.+?(?=>)>.*<c>` It matches everything from the first `<c...` to the last `<c>`. What I want is each of those substrings as one item. How can I do this and if I can't do it with regex, what would be the best way to achieve my goal.

Comment: Remove `(?=>)`, and try to understand how your pattern works, you will find the solution.

Comment: This might be some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452/regex-match-multiple-times-in-string

Comment: are you just wanting the text inside those tags?

Comment: @Jonesy No I want the text inside the tags, and the tags itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string input = @"This combination of plain text and <c=@flavor> colored text<c> is valid. <c=@warning>Multiple tags are also valid.<c>";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"<c=@(.+?)>(.+?)<c>")
                .Cast<Match>()
                .Select(m => new
                {
                    Name = m.Groups[1].Value,
                    Value = m.Groups[2].Value
                })
                .ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. While @Jonesy also has good code, yours is more clear and has no strings to select the groups.

Answer (score 1):

You can use named capture groups, along with lookaheads and lookbehinds, to grab the 'type' and 'text':

```
var pattern = @"(?<=<c=@)(?<type>[^>]+)>(?<text>.+?)(?=<c>)";
var str = @"This combination of plain text and <c=@flavor> colored text<c> is valid. <c=@warning>Multiple tags are also valid.<c>";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, pattern))
{
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["type"].Value);
   Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["text"].Value);

   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

output:

```
flavor
 colored text

warning
Multiple tags are also valid.
```

pattern:

`(?<=<c=@)           :` Look for `<c=@`

`(?<type>[^>]+)>     :` Grab everything until a `>`, call it `type`

`(?<text>.+?)        :` Grab everything until the lookahead, call it `text`

`(?=<c>)             :` Stop when you find a `<c>`