# Extract all substrings from string between defined delimiter into string array

Tags: c#, regex, string, split, substring

I need some kind of method , using regex or split I don't know that does the following.

I have string that looks like this:

```
ls 0 
[0,86,180]
ls 1 
[1,2,200]
ls 2 
[2,3,180]
ls 3 
[3,4,234]
```

...and so on. I want everything between parenthesis [ ] to be one string inside string array, and everything else disregard

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract text that lies between parentheses (round brackets)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/378415/how-do-i-extract-text-that-lies-between-parentheses-round-brackets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Regex like the the [following](https://regex101.com/r/jL5gL2/1) should work.

`(\[[\d]*,[\d]*,[\d]*\]*)`

You just need to read multiple matches as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452/regex-match-multiple-times-in-string).

Comment: unrecognized escape sequence when trying to create regex

Answer (score 1):

This may give you the whole idea and steps:

```
var yourString = @"ls 0 
        [0,86,180]
        ls 1 
        [1,2,200]
        ls 2 
        [2,3,180]
        ls 3 
        [3,4,234]";

var result = yourString.Split(new char[] { '\n' })                //split
                       .Where(i => i.Contains('['))               //filter
                       .Select(i => i.Replace("[", string.Empty)  //prepare
                                     .Replace("]", string.Empty))
                       .ToList();

var newArray = string.Join(",", result);                          //merge the result
```

Answer (score 0):

In case number blocks aren't always in sets of threes

```
 var myString = "ls 0 
    [0,86,190]
    ls 1 
    [1,2,300]
    ls 2 
    [2,3,185]
    ls 3 
    [3,4,2345]";

    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\[[\d,]*\]*");
    Match numbers = pattern.Match(myString);

    if(numbers.Success)
    {
      do {
          var val = numbers.Value;

          // code for each block of numbers

          numbers.NextMatch();
          } while(numbers.Success)
    }
```