# Replacing the character between angle brackets

Tags: c#, regex, string

Story: 
I have a list box that shows all the methods of the current application. I need to colorize the method parameters' data type to blue.

Solution: FIRST, I extract the content between the parenthesis. SECOND, I want to split them by COMMA

Problem:
If the arguments entail something like `IDictionary<string, string>` which occurs multiple times, then the above solution faces problem!! Thus, I decided to FIRST grab all the content between the angle brackets and then Replace their comma with `"#COMMA#"` and after performing the task using the above solution simply replace the `"#COMMA#"` with ",". BUT, based on the solution found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452/regex-match-multiple-times-in-string), it is not possible to set any value to `match.value`. Here is my code:

```
if (methodArgumentType.Contains("<") && methodArgumentType.Contains(">"))
        {
            var regex = new Regex("(?<=<).*?(?=>)");
            foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(methodArgumentType))
            {
                match.Value = match.Value.Replace(",", "#COMMA#");
            }
        }
```

Any suggestion highly appreciated.

Comment: @Tushar: I don't think if the regex pattern has a problem. Actually, `match.Value` is read-only, cant be replaced. Maybe I need to do something else

Comment: OMG. You just can do it with `methodArgumentType = Regex.Replace(methodArgumentType, @"<([^<>]+)>", m => string.Format("<{0}>", m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(",", "#COMMA#")))`. Then, `IDictionary<string, string>` will turn into `IDictionary<string#COMMA# string>`. Is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: fixed pattern to `@"<([^<>]+)>"`.

Comment: why not just use Roslyn to get the syntax tree for the code?

Comment: @stribizhev: Thanks a lot for the help. It helped a lot. Sorry, I am not that much confident with Regex concept

Comment: @Keith Hall: I am not familiar with Rosyln. Consider that I have a String which is a list box item. Does it help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the matched value *inside the match evaluator within `Regex.Replace`*:

```
var methodArgumentType = "IDictionary<string, string>";
if (methodArgumentType.Contains("<") && methodArgumentType.Contains(">"))
{
    methodArgumentType = Regex.Replace(methodArgumentType, @"<([^<>]+)>", 
        m => string.Format("<{0}>", m.Groups[1].Value.Replace(",", "#COMMA#")));
}
Console.WriteLine(methodArgumentType);
// => IDictionary<string#COMMA# string>
```

[Here](http://ideone.com/hJuqS5), `m.Groups[1].Value` will hold `string, string` and the replacement will be done on the input string itself, not the `Regex.Match` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the helpful answer