# C# regex find specific character between tags

Tags: c#, regex

really just started using regex and can only do basic things.

I want to convert hyphens in the element tag of an XML file to underscores.  I already have a c# app that reads a config file with find and replace elements and does some other cleaning work in RegEx but can't figure this one out

so currently it will go in as

> < convert-there-here > but-not-these < / convert-these-here >

And I want it spat out as

> < convert_these_here > but-not-these < / convert_these_here >

The C# script jut sucks in the file and reads it line by line, it doesn't look at it as an xml file

so basically i thought i just need a pattern that looks for any and all hyphens BETWEEN  a < and >

Thanks

Comment: It is very easy with infinite width lookbehind and a lookahead in .NET. If you want to process the XML as TXT, you can try [this code here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34658897/3832970)

Comment: Process it as an XML file... you'll save yourself having to write an XML parser using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks but i just want to clean this and already passing it through a regex and want to also add this one

Comment: If there is a simple string to do this please let me know

Comment: @JQuery It's a complete wtf to use anything other than an XML parser to do this. Don't be the fool who thinks that parsing XML with regular expressions is a good idea. It isn't. Really. Anyone who helps you down this path can expect a dv from me.

Comment: Ok but I'm not using C# to process the XML.  I want prepare it because the files are crap and are out of our control.  How would an XML parser convert hyphens in the element name to under scores?  or convert sub and super script tags to be html encoded?

without an XSD file i should add...

I have no control over the xml files i have to process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ditch the regex. Parse your XML, and fix it. Using the `XDocument` class makes this really easy.

Say we start with the following XML document:

```
<this-is>
  <an-xml>
    <doc but-I="remain-untouched">look-at-me</doc>
  </an-xml>
</this-is>
```

We can load it into an `XDocument` and fix up the element names.

```
var str = "<this-is><an-xml><doc but-I=\"remain-untouched\">look-at-me</doc></an-xml></this-is>";
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);
foreach(var el in xdoc.Descendants())
{
    var name = el.Name.LocalName;
    name = name.Replace("-", "_");
    el.Name = el.Name.Namespace + name;

}
var fixedXmlString = xdoc.ToString();
```

Now this gives us the following:

```
<this_is>
  <an_xml>
    <doc but-I="remain-untouched">look-at-me</doc>
  </an_xml>
</this_is>
```

Comment: thanks spender, I'll try this, stupid question but the var str should that point to the actual xml file?

Comment: @JQuery Indeed. It's a string containing the XML you want to fix. You might instead, choose to load it using `XDocument.Load`.

Comment: Ok but it isn't one particular string, its any hyphen inside a < and >  I should add i want to ignore any hyphens in quotes that may appear in there

Comment: The code I posted takes the whole document and replaces hyphens with underscores in the element names. It won't replace them in attribute names or attribute values or in text elements. I suggest you spend a while getting to terms with the underlying concepts of XML, because from your questions, it's clear you don't really understand the different constituents of an XML document. Did you try running the code?

Comment: Thanks mate, im going to try it now.  I understand XML but not so much in a C# way.  I process it through SSIS but the files we have are not proper XML and have a lot of crap in there that need cleaning first.  The hyphens are not so much and issue but as SSIS converts the elements directly to tables having under scores makes them a correct table name where as a hyphen isn't and requires wrapping them un square brackets

Comment: for the line: var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(str);

I'm getting an error - an unhandled exception of type 'System.Xml.XmlException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, porition 1

Comment: not sure if your code expects hard coded xml text? but i added this to load it into a string first:

var xDocument = XDocument.Load(@"C:\test.xml");
            string str = xDocument.ToString();

Comment: and get an out of memory exception.

Comment: i had a look into it and chjanged xdocument.parse to x.document.load and then xdocument.save for the output and it seems to have worked!

Comment: @JQuery Glad you got there in the end.

Comment: Thanks mate really helped

Comment: Because this contains html tags like <sub> <b> <i> I have used the reg ex to find and replace them, been able to maintain an xml config file i can add too.  Using the method above, is there a way to find html tags and encode the inner string? Generically?