# How to select whole text without special characters in single match?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some text, I need to select only alphanumeric characters only in single match.

I have tried this in regex

```
[^\W]+

Pattern : [^\W]+

Input:  This is "My Page"
```

https://rubular.com/r/PMQwahJIqqiOOI

Output I Need: `This is My Page`

Comment: Join the result with a single space? This will avoid the capture of multiple space

Comment: The only way is to remove the non-alphanumeric characters. Or concatenate the sub-matches.

Comment: BTW, concatenating matches is preferable if spaces should not be preserved and you want to get alphanumeric substrings separated with a single space: it is much cleaner with a mere `\w+` regex. See [this thread on how to get multiple matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452).

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything that is not word character or space using this regex,

```
[^\w ]+
```

with empty space.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v3aesT/1)**